# When downloading images and save them to hard disk after 2 images getting gdi exception why?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using mshtml;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace Extract_Images
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private int numberoflinks = 13;
        private int currentLinkNumber = 0;
        private string mainlink;
        private WebBrowser webBrowser1;
        private bool firsturltonav = false;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();
            webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
            webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;
            label1.Text = "Number of links: ";
            mainlink = "http://www.test.com";
        }

        private void ProcessFirstLink()
        {
            string firstLink = mainlink;
            firsturltonav = true;
            webBrowser1.Navigate(firstLink);
        }

        private void ProcessNextLink()
        {
            if (currentLinkNumber < numberoflinks)
            {
                currentLinkNumber++;
                string linktonav = mainlink + "index"+currentLinkNumber.ToString() + ".html";
                label1.Text = currentLinkNumber.ToString();
                webBrowser1.Navigate(linktonav);
            }
        }

        int count = 0;
        void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            mshtml.HTMLDocument objHtmlDoc = (mshtml.HTMLDocument)webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument;
            string pageSource = objHtmlDoc.documentElement.innerHTML;

            if (firsturltonav == true)
                ParseNumberOfLinks();

            string[] hrefs = this.webBrowser1.Document.Links.Cast<HtmlElement>()
             .Select(a => a.GetAttribute("href")).Where(h => h.Contains(".jpg")).ToArray();

            foreach(string a in hrefs)
            {
                var result = GetImageAsync(a);
                result.ContinueWith(task =>
                {                    
                        task.Result.Save(@"C:\images\file" + count + ".jpg");
                        pictureBox1.Image = task.Result;
                        count++;
                        label2.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { label2.Text = count.ToString(); }));
                }); 
            }
            ProcessNextLink();
        }

        public async Task<Image> GetImageAsync(string url)
        {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Image>();
            Image webImage = null;
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = "GET";
            await Task.Factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, null)
                .ContinueWith(task =>
                {
                    var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)task.Result;
                    Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
                    if (webResponse.ContentEncoding.ToLower().Contains("gzip"))
                        responseStream = new GZipStream(responseStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
                    else if (webResponse.ContentEncoding.ToLower().Contains("deflate"))
                        responseStream = new DeflateStream(responseStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);

                    if (responseStream != null) webImage = Image.FromStream(responseStream);
                    tcs.TrySetResult(webImage);
                    webResponse.Close();
                    responseStream.Close();
                });
            return tcs.Task.Result;
        }

        private void ParseNumberOfLinks()
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ProcessNextLink();
        }
    }
}
```

The exception is on the line:

```
task.Result.Save(@"C:\images\file" + count + ".jpg");
```

The first two images are saved fine but then the exception is thrown:

A generic error occurred in GDI+

If i'm using try and catch i see in the StackTrace:

at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
       at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageFormat format)
       at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename)
       at Extract_Images.Form1.b__2(Task`1 task) in d:\C-Sharp\Extract_Images\Extract_Images\Extract_Images\Form1.cs:line 76

Line 76 is:

```
task.Result.Save(@"C:\images\file" + count + ".jpg");
```

Comment: Without a good [mcve], it would be impossible to say for sure what the issue is. But usually an exception like that just means you are trying to save the image that has an unsupported format, at least for saving. I don't understand why you wrote the code the way you did. If you're just trying to download images from a web server and save them as a file, it seems to me that you ought to just copy the downloaded bytes straight to the file, rather than actually interpreting them as an `Image` object and then saving that `Image` object.

Comment: @PeterDuniho The reason i'm using webbrowser is that only this way i can get the source content of the pages. And the reason i'm using async task is since i want to display the images in real time in the pictureBox1 one by one. Could you show me then how the code should be please including saving the images the right way ?

Comment: You're creating the `Image` object from a `Stream`. Just use `Stream.CopyTo()`, to copy the data to a `FileStream`, instead of making the `Image` object from the data. You can still display the image too...just read it from the `FileStream` you create.

Comment: @PeterDuniho in the bottom of the GetImageAsync method before webResponse close and responseStream close 3 lines: fs = new FileStream(url, FileMode.Create);
                    responseStream.CopyTo(fs);
                    fs.Close(); is that right ? And how do i read it in the foreach loop to save the images and display them in the pictureBox ?